# How does `chmod +x` work in cygwin?

Tags: windows, cygwin, file-permissions

I just downloaded an executable via cygwin's wget and found I cannot execute it.

In cygwin I get

```
$ ./clink_0.4.4_setup.exe
-bash: ./clink_0.4.4_setup.exe: Permission denied
```

and when I try to execute it from explorer, I get

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have appropriate permissions to access the item.

This seems clear - in Linux/Unix, I would `chmod +x`, and indeed that works here, too. But I thought Windows doesn't have the "executable" bit. I can imagine that cygwin stores its permissions in Alternate Data Streams, and can prevent me from executing it, but how does it enforce this outside of cygwin? I can't find anything obvious in the file's properties (in explorer).

Answer (score 3):

#### How does `chmod +x` work in cygwin?

You need to read **all** of [Chapter 3. Using Cygwin- POSIX accounts, permission, and security](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html) to completely understand this.

Some extracts follow.

---

#### POSIX accounts, permission, and security

> This section discusses how the Windows security model is utilized in
>   Cygwin to implement POSIX account information, POSIX-like permissions,
>   and how the Windows authentication model is used to allow cygwin
>   applications to switch users in a POSIX-like fashion.
>
> The setting of POSIX-like file and directory permissions is controlled
>   by the mount option (no)acl which is set to acl by default.
>
> We start with a short overview. Note that this overview must be
>   necessarily short. If you want to learn more about the Windows
>   security model, see the Access Control article in MSDN documentation.
>
> POSIX concepts and in particular the POSIX security model are not
>   discussed here, but assumed to be understood by the reader. If you
>   don't know the POSIX security model, search the web for beginner
>   documentation.

#### Brief overview of Windows security

> In the Windows security model, almost any "object" is securable.
>   "Objects" are files, processes, threads, semaphores, etc.
>
> Every object has a data structure attached, called a "security
>   descriptor" (SD). The SD contains all information necessary to control
>   who can access an object, and to determine what they are allowed to do
>   to or with it. The SD of an object consists of five parts:
>
> - Flags which control several aspects of this SD. This is not discussed here.
> - The SID of the object owner.
> - The SID of the object owner group.
> - A list of "Access Control Entries" (ACE), called the "Discretionary Access Control List" (DACL).
> - Another list of ACEs, called the "Security Access Control List" (SACL), which doesn't matter for our purpose. We ignore it here.
>
> Every ACE contains a so-called "Security IDentifier" (SID) and other
>   stuff which is explained a bit later. Let's talk about the SID first.
>
> A SID is a unique identifier for users, groups, computers and Active
>   Directory (AD) domains. SIDs are basically comparable to POSIX user
>   ids (UIDs) and group ids (GIDs), but are more complicated because they
>   are unique across multiple machines or domains. A SID is a structure
>   of multiple numerical values. There's a convenient convention to type
>   SIDs, as a string of numerical fields separated by hyphen characters.

...

#### File permissions

> On NTFS and if the noacl mount option is not specified for a mount
>   point, Cygwin sets file permissions as on POSIX systems. Basically
>   this is done by defining a Security Descriptor with the matching owner
>   and group SIDs, and a DACL which contains ACEs for the owner, the
>   group and for "Everyone", which represents what POSIX calls "others".
>
> There's just one problem when trying to map the POSIX permission model
>   onto the Windows permission model.
>
> There's a leak in the definition of a "correct" ACL which disallows a
>   certain POSIX permission setting. The official documentation explains
>   in short the following:
>
> - The requested permissions are checked against all ACEs of the user as well as all groups the user is member of. The permissions
>     given in these user and groups access allowed ACEs are accumulated and
>     the resulting set is the set of permissions of that user given for
>     that object.
> - The order of ACEs is important. The system reads them in sequence until either any single requested permission is denied or all
>     requested permissions are granted. Reading stops when this condition
>     is met. Later ACEs are not taken into account.
> - All access denied ACEs should precede any access allowed ACE. ACLs following this rule are called "canonical".
>
> Note that the last rule is a preference or a definition of
>   correctness. It's not an absolute requirement. All Windows kernels
>   will correctly deal with the ACL regardless of the order of allow and
>   deny ACEs. The second rule is not modified to get the ACEs in the
>   preferred order.
>
> Unfortunately the security tab in the file properties dialog of the
>   Windows Explorer insists to rearrange the order of the ACEs to
>   canonical order before you can read them. Thank God, the sort order
>   remains unchanged if one presses the Cancel button. But don't even
>   think of pressing OK...
>
> Canonical ACLs are unable to reflect each possible combination of
>   POSIX permissions. Example:
>
> ```
> rw-r-xrw-
> ```
>
> Ok, so here's the first try to create a matching ACL, assuming the
>   Windows permissions only have three bits, as their POSIX counterpart:
>
> ```
> UserAllow:   110
> GroupAllow:  101
> OthersAllow: 110
> ```
>
> Hmm, because of the accumulation of allow rights the user may execute
>   because the group may execute.
>
> Second try:
>
> ```
> UserDeny:    001
> GroupAllow:  101
> OthersAllow: 110
> ```
>
> Now the user may read and write but not execute. Better? No!
>   Unfortunately the group may write now because others may write.
>
> Third try:
>
> ```
> UserDeny:    001
> GroupDeny:   010
> GroupAllow:  001
> OthersAllow: 110
> ```
>
> Now the group may not write as intended but unfortunately the user may
>   not write anymore, either. How should this problem be solved?
>   According to the canonical order a UserAllow has to follow the
>   GroupDeny but it's easy to see that this can never be solved that way.
>
> The only chance:
>
> ```
> UserDeny:    001
> UserAllow:   010
> GroupDeny:   010
> GroupAllow:  001
> OthersAllow: 110
> ```
>
> Again: This works on all existing versions of Windows NT, at the time
>   of writing from at least Windows XP up to Server 2012 R2. Only the
>   GUIs aren't able (or willing) to deal with that order.

Source [POSIX accounts, permission, and security](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html)

---

#### Further reading

- [Chapter 3. Using Cygwin- POSIX accounts, permission, and security](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html)
- [Access Control Lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [4.3 Discretionary Access Control Lists (DACLs) and Access Control Entries (ACEs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc246052.aspx)
- [How Security Descriptors and Access Control Lists Work](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc781716%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)
- [Permissions: A Primer, or: DACL, SACL, Owner, SID and ACE Explained](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2009/03/permissions-a-primer-or-dacl-sacl-owner-sid-and-ace-explained/?PageSpeed=noscript)

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin attempts to emulates file permissions. Windows does have security descriptors which are similar: Traverse directory / Execute file is in fact a permission which can be granted or denied to any user or group; Check the security tab.